# What to use as array_import/var_import for sort-of exported array?

Tags: php, arrays, import, export

I have a string. It's a user submitted string. (And you should never ever trust user submitted anything.)

If certain (not unsafe) characters exist in the string, it's supposed to become a multi dimensional array/tree. First I tried splits, regex and loops. Too difficult. I've found a very easy solution with a few simple `str_replace`'s and the result is a **string** that looks like an array definition. Eg:

```
array('body', array('div', array('x'), array(), array('')), array(array('oele')))
```

It's a silly array, but it's very easily created. Now that string has to become that array. I'm using `eval()` for that and I don't like it. Since it's user submitted (and must be able to contain just about anything), there could be any sort of function calls in that string.

So the million dollar question: is there some kind of `var_import`, or `array_import` that creates an array from a string **and does nothing else** (like mysterious, dangerous calls to `exec` etc)?

Yes, I have tried php.net and neither of the above `_import` functions exist.

What I'm looking for is the exact opposite of [`var_import`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), becasuse the string I have as input, looks exactly like the string `var_export` would output.

Any other suggestions to make it safer then `eval` are also welcome! But I'm not abandoning the current method (it's just too simple).

Comment: How is the user input string split up/array tree structure decided upon what?

Comment: It's impossible to parse a php array. I'd use JSON format to define arrays as strings: `["body",["div",["x"],[],[""]],[["oele"]]]`. Then you could just do [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: I don't decide what the user submitted string looks like. Its format has been decided. The best I can make of it, is the above 'array as string'. @meze Maybe I can convert the php-array-string to a json-string and then use json_decode..?

Comment: @meze You the man! I converted the user submitted string to JSON (instead of PHP array) and then I can safely import it.

Comment: Instead of editing the question with [SOLVED], you should answer your question and accept the answer.

Comment: @Luc I didn't quite come up with it myself. The idea was meze's. @meze If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
array('body', array('div', array('x'), array(), array('')), array(array('oele')))
```

as input, I replaced some chars to make it a valid JSON string and imported that via `json_decode`.

Works perfectly. If some illegal chars are present, `json_decode` will trip over them (and not execute any dangerous code).